# calling setState on a reactjs component with test utils not re-rendering component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have the following code in a jest based test:

```
it('will show the hero loop if there is one', function() {

    var React = require('react/addons');
    var ShowsDetailHeader = require('../../../../routes/shows/components/ShowsDetailHeader.jsx');
    var mockData = require('../../../../mock/episodeDetailData');
    mockData.data.show.assets._webHeroVideoUrl = 'https://test.video.com';

    var Subject = require('../../../../mock/stubRouterContext')(ShowsDetailHeader,  {
      show: mockData.data.show
    });

    var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

    var showsHeader = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <Subject />
    );

    showsHeader.setState({
      showVideo: true
    });

    var videoClass = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(showsHeader, 'flex-video').getDOMNode().getAttribute('class');

    expect(videoClass.indexOf('in')).toBe(-1);

    console.log(videoClass);


  });
```

My previous test tests the initial state of the component. I now want to call setState to check the component after a state change. The videoClass i'm logging here stays the same. I am on react 0.12. and latest jest 0.4.0.

Any ideas on how to test what happens after set state?

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is async, so you probably need

```
showsHeader.setState({
      showVideo: true
    });
jest.runAllTicks();
find ...
expect ...
```

But I think state should be private and shouldn't be direct changed, state should be change inside a component, cause by ui event or data change.
an option is using`props` for public, if you wanna change the component from outside.

Comment: yes, state is private, but in this particular case in the rest of the component i'm listening for an event to occur on a video element, and the handler is called when this event occurs. I can at least I suppose call that method instead of setState directly. awesome, i'm still new to jest. willl test that out then mark answered.

Comment: runAllTicks didn't help the matter. also, unrelated, I can't seem to call the method that's changing state, just keep on getting Object object has no method [methodName].

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to test setting State with Jest and React Test Utils, mind a look here if you have a moment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399181/react-jest-how-to-test-changing-state-in-component-and-checking-for-another-co