# how to test react arrow function dealing with statefull component state

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have statefull component with arrow function.
This function is dealing with component state.

```
    onMovieFindHandler = () => {
    let result = {...this.state.movies};

    if (this.state.sortBy.sortByTitle) {
        result = this.state.movies.filter(movie => movie.title.includes(this.state.searchQuery));
    } else {
        result = this.state.movies.filter(movie => movie.genre.includes(this.state.searchQuery));
    }

    this.setState({ movies: result });
}
```

I'm using this function in my child components.

```
 return (
        <ErrorBoundary>
            <SearchPanel 
                titleHandler={this.onTitleFilterHandler}
                genreHandler={this.onGenreFilterHandler}
                inputChangeHandler={this.onInputChangeHandler}
                sorting={this.state.sortBy}
                searchHandler={this.onMovieFindHandler} />
            <StatusBar moviesAmount={this.state.movies.length} />
            {movieCards}
            <Footer />
        </ErrorBoundary>
    )
```

My tool-set for testing: Jest/Enzyme
How can I test this function?

I tried to do it in this way:

```
    it('component should filter movies by search query', () => {
    const movieHandlerMock = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<MovieFinder searchQuery="Fifty" />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    expect(instance.state.movies.length).toEqual(6);
    instance.onMovieFindHandler();
    expect(instance.onMovieFindHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(instance.state.movies.length).toEqual(1);
})
```

But last "expect" returns 6 instead of 1.

Component code: https://jsbin.com/kibomituni/edit?js,output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React + Jest how to test changing state in component and checking for another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399181/react-jest-how-to-test-changing-state-in-component-and-checking-for-another-co)

Comment: can you share your component as well here so that we can get an Idea how sortBy is passed ? That could be the reason that the sortBy value is not assigned properly.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/kibomituni/edit?js,output

Comment: @Matthew not duplicate, it's totally different.
Here I need to understand how to test function that dealing with state in the same statefull container component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a component within your shallow wrapper using the [find](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html) method and you can access a specific prop being passed down by using the [prop](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/prop.html) method. This means that you can simulate a function prop being called from the child component:

```
it('component should filter movies by search query', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MovieFinder searchQuery="Fifty" />);
  expect(wrapper.state().movies.length).toEqual(6);

  wrapper.find('SearchPanel').prop('searchHandler')();

  expect(wrapper.state().movies.length).toEqual(1);
})
```

I think this is all you should be checking with unit tests - ie checking that the effects have been applied, rather than checking that an internal method has been called. However, if you want to explicitly assert that `onMovieFindHandler` has been called then you could add in a couple of lines:

```
it('component should filter movies by search query', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MovieFinder searchQuery="Fifty" />);
  expect(wrapper.state().movies.length).toEqual(6);

  const instance = wrapper.instance();
  jest.spyOn(instance, 'onMovieFindHandler');

  wrapper.find('SearchPanel').prop('searchHandler')();

  expect(wrapper.state().movies.length).toEqual(1);
  expect(instance.onMovieFindHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

EDIT:

you need to set the searchQuery state with the prop that gets passed in - to do this change your constructor to:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        movies: [
            {
                title: 'Fifty Shades Freed',
                genre: 'Action',
                year: '2001',
                imgUrl: '123'
            },
            {
                title: 'Zootopia',
                genre: 'Drama',
                year: '2007',
                imgUrl: '123'
            },
            {
                title: 'Star Wars The Last Jedi',
                genre: 'Comedes',
                year: '1998',
                imgUrl: '123'
            },
            {
                title: 'Black Panther',
                genre: 'Adventure',
                year: '2010',
                imgUrl: '123'
            },
            {
                title: 'Coco',
                genre: 'Action',
                year: '2004',
                imgUrl: '123'
            },
            {
                title: 'Thor Ragnarok',
                genre: 'Drama',
                year: '2003',
                imgUrl: '123'
            }
        ],
        sortBy: {
            sortByTitle: true,
            sortByGenre: false,
        },
        searchQuery: props.searchQuery
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I tried both solutions, but no one is working.
1st solution:     Expected value to equal:
      1
    Received:
      6
2nd solution: the same

Seems like onMovieFindHandler was not called.

Comment: okay I see the problem - the searchQuery state is always `''`. You need to take the value passed in as a prop and set it in the state. I've updated my answer to show you how to do this