# How to test return function value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jestjs

How can I test the return value for this function ?

```
handleValidatePassword = (confirmPassword) => {
    const { newPassword } = this.props;
    if (newPassword !== confirmPassword) {
      return <FormattedMessage id="some value" />;
    }
  }
```

I need to check if the returned value of this function is the expected one if condition is right:(FormattedMessage return span with value === id)

```
<span> some value </span>
```

i'm using shallow from enzyme for test

Comment: You should explain better what you want to do

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What are you using to render your component in the tests (Could it be enzyme?)

Comment: In function put console.log(changePass.alerts.notMatch); before return.

Comment: using import { shallow } from 'enzyme' for test

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use enzyme-matchers if you use jest or jasmine f.e. https://github.com/FormidableLabs/enzyme-matchers/blob/master/packages/jest-enzyme/README.md#tocontainreact

```js
import { shallow } from 'enzyme' 
import Element from './yourpath'

const wrapper = shallow(<Element />); // mount/render/shallow when applicable

//as shallow renders only one level of children components
expect(wrapper).toContainReact(<FormattedMessage id="some value" />);

//or if you want to test actually the span element you should use mount
const wrapper2 = mount(<Element />);
expect(wrapper).toContainReact(<span> some value </span>);
```

Comment: does not work because <FormattedMessage> does not exist when the component is mounted, I have a condition inside the function, so I need to check that the function will return if the condition is met correctly, but thanks for this information, this will help me in the future. I need test just that function will return

Comment: For example -- `    wrapper.instance().handleValidatePassword = jest.fn();
    wrapper.instance().handleValidatePassword.mockReturnValue(<span> changePass.alerts.notMatch </span>);` But this does not work to

Comment: Can you share component code where you are using this function?

Is this condition in code depends on the state of component? If so then you can use setState in the tests [f.e. like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399181/react-jest-how-to-test-changing-state-and-checking-for-another-component)

Comment: Can I verify that this function will return? As if it is independent of components and other things

Comment: or maybe I can somehow check if the condition works (example: newPassword !== confirmPassword)

Comment: Yes you should be able to verify what this function will return as it was just normal component. Maybe you should create component that is always rendered but it's null in case that those password matches?

```const InvalidPasswordValidation = ({newPassword, confirmPassword}) => newPassword !== confirmPassword ? <FormattedMessage id="some value" /> : null;```

Comment: @ДенисКлименко Did it helped you? If so mark it as resolved