# How can I test a React Hooks component by changing useState

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I have a React hooks functional component that I'd like to test with Jest/Enzyme.  I would like test its tertiary render behaviour based upon a useState value.  I can't seem to find any example online.  There is no 'click' to simulate - no API call to mock because at the end, I still need to test based upon the useState value.
In the past, with class components, I could set the state.  With the new hooks, I can't.
So, basically - how do I mock an async await inside a mocked submitForm function so that the render behaves properly?

Here's my component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import Form from 'core/Form';

export const Parent = ({submitForm}) => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({});
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = name => evt => {
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: evt.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await submitForm(formValues);
        if (res) setRedirect(true);
        else setRedirect(false);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Submit error: ', err);
      }
  };

  return redirect ? (
    <Redirect push to={path} />
  ) : (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} values={formValues} onChange={handleChange} />
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Here's my testing so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import Parent from './Parent';
import Form from 'core/Form';

let wrapper, props;
.
.
.

describe('<Parent /> rendering', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    props = createTestProps();
    wrapper = shallow(<Parent {...props} />);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  const setState = jest.fn();
  const useStateSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useState');
  useStateSpy.mockImplementation(init => [init, setState]);

  it('Should render 1 Form', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(Form)).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it('renders Redirect after API call', () => {
    setRedirect = jest.fn(() => false);

    expect(wrapper.find(Redirect)).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it('renders Form before API call', () => {
    setRedirect = jest.fn(() => true);

    expect(wrapper.find(Form)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't have been directly setting the state for testing previously, either! That's *implementation*, not behaviour - ideally, you should be able to switch back and forth between functional and class components *without* changing the tests, for example. The state is set by the Form child component, so if you're shallow rendering you could mock out that component to get access to the setter, or do a deeper render and actually interact with the Form.

Comment: Why would you mark me down for not knowing something I am asking a question about?
Also, your answer is confusing.

Comment: Here's an example from another SO reply directly setting state.

it('should render the Notification component if state.error is true', () => {
    const loginComponent = shallow(<Login />);
    loginComponent.setState({ error: true });
    expect(loginComponent.find(Notification).length).toBe(1);
});

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399181/react-jest-how-to-test-changing-state-and-checking-for-another-component

Comment: The fact that it was possible (and that user wanted to do it) didn't make it right! See e.g. https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/faq for a library that deliberately implements a less-coupled philosophy.

Comment: Also, you haven't understood my question. You wrote - "The state is set by the Form child component" - which is incorrect.  If that were so, I'd simply 'mount' instead of 'shallow' and simulate the submit button click of the child Form component.  However, the state is set by the truthiness of the response of an API call.  The submit button simply initiates the call in the parent.

Comment: I thought you said *"no API call to mock"*? Looking again at the example it seems like *nothing* sets the form values (or at least calls setFormValues, the object may be getting mutated somewhere). setRedirect is called based on submitForm, which is a prop that presumably comes from createTestProps (not shown) so could easily be mocked. The local setRedirects in the tests aren't connected to the component at all, not sure what you expected there. What element of the state both: 1. ever changes; *and* 2. isn't changed by interaction with the DOM or a collaborator? Give a [mcve] of that.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't want to clutter the example code.  setFormValues is being set, but not included - hence the 3 dots.

Comment: I edited the code to include setFormValues.

Comment: So the state update *is* triggered by the Form component? I return to my first comment.

Comment: Not the 'redirect' prop though, the one related to my unit test question, not the form values - hence why i omitted that part of the code - precisely to avoid this confusion :-)

Comment: I think the easiest way to do it here is to provide a custom `submitForm` and trigger the submit on the form. This way you can test the real flow of the component. Let me know if its not clear.

Comment: It's clear.  But - custom form in a unit test?

Comment: 1. Then why leave references to it in the example at all? Re-read [mcve]; having an unused state setter lying around doesn't exactly make things less confusing! 2. Could you clarify your question about *"custom form"*? As I also pointed out previously, submitForm, to which the other commenter refers, is just a prop; you can easily pass in a test double at that boundary when rendering the component.

Comment: Jonrsharpe - I don't need to be scolded.
Alvaro - thank you for your suggestion.  On re-reading, I now realized that ```submitForm``` isn't a component but a function prop.  My bad.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to spy `useState` hook. Which means you should not test these hooks and methods of the component directly. Instead, you should test components' behavior(the `state`, `props` and what is rendered)

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Form = ({ onSubmit, onChange, values }) => <form onSubmit={onSubmit}></form>;
const path = '/user';

export const Parent = ({ submitForm }) => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({});
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (name) => (evt) => {
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: evt.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await submitForm(formValues);
      if (res) setRedirect(true);
      else setRedirect(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Submit error: ', err);
    }
  };

  return redirect ? (
    <Redirect push to={path} />
  ) : (
    <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} values={formValues} onChange={handleChange} />
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import Parent, { Form } from './';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

const whenStable = async () =>
  await act(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
  });

describe('60137762', () => {
  it('should render Form', () => {
    const props = { submitForm: jest.fn() };
    const wrapper = shallow(<Parent {...props}></Parent>);
    expect(wrapper.find(Form)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should handle submit and render Redirect', async () => {
    const props = { submitForm: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(true) };
    const wrapper = shallow(<Parent {...props}></Parent>);
    wrapper.find(Form).simulate('submit');
    await whenStable();
    expect(props.submitForm).toBeCalledWith({});
    expect(wrapper.find(Redirect)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should handle submit and render Form', async () => {
    const props = { submitForm: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(false) };
    const wrapper = shallow(<Parent {...props}></Parent>);
    wrapper.find(Form).simulate('submit');
    await whenStable();
    expect(props.submitForm).toBeCalledWith({});
    expect(wrapper.find(Form)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should handle error if submit failure', async () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const mError = new Error('network');
    const props = { submitForm: jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce(mError) };
    const wrapper = shallow(<Parent {...props}></Parent>);
    wrapper.find(Form).simulate('submit');
    await whenStable();
    expect(props.submitForm).toBeCalledWith({});
    expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Submit error: ', mError);
  });
});
```

Unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60137762/index.test.tsx
  60137762
    ✓ should render Form (18ms)
    ✓ should handle submit and render Redirect (15ms)
    ✓ should handle submit and render Form (8ms)
    ✓ should handle error if submit failure (18ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-environment-enzyme/node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:866
    Submit error:  Error: network
        at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/stackoverflow/60137762/index.test.tsx:39:20
        at step (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/stackoverflow/60137762/index.test.tsx:44:23)
        at Object.next (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/stackoverflow/60137762/index.test.tsx:25:53)
        at /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/stackoverflow/60137762/index.test.tsx:19:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/stackoverflow/60137762/index.test.tsx:15:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/stackoverflow/60137762/index.test.tsx:37:47)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:100:37)
        at resolve (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:43:12)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:26:19)
        at promise.then (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:73:41)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |   78.57 |      100 |      40 |   93.75 |                   
 index.tsx |   78.57 |      100 |      40 |   93.75 | 12                
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.716s, estimated 5s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/60137762

Comment: I'm getting this: ```Warning: The callback passed to ReactTestUtils.act(...) function must not return anything.``` .  Any ideas?

Comment: The above occurs when executing ```await whenStable();``` Could it be a React version issue?