# How to test onClose prop with Jest and ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

I have a component looking like this, when the button is clicked a modal opens, when X button is clicked, mouse is pressed or esc key is pressed modal closes and calls `onClose` function, however, Jest report says `setIsOpen(false);` is not covered.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
 
  return (
    <div className="container">
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setIsOpen(true);
            }}
          />
      <Flow
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onClose={() => {
          setIsOpen(false);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

How can I test if `setIsOpen(false);` is being called? I tried mocking the `useState` and check if it was being called, however, this messed up the `setIsOpen(true);` in the button, being a mock, the modal won't open.

Any ideas?

Comment: > How can I test setIsOpen(false);? You shouldn't. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60137762/how-can-i-test-a-react-hooks-component-by-changing-usestate

Comment: Thank you @Suver1 I'm trying to verify if that is being called, not trying to check the value of the state

Answer (score 2):

I will use [Enzyme](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/) to test the behavior of react component.

> Enzyme is a JavaScript Testing utility for React that makes it easier to test your React Components' output

You can use [.invoke(invokePropName)(...args) => Any](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/invoke.html) of shallow wrapper to invoke `onClose()` method of `Flow` component.

E.g.

`MyComponent.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Flow } from './Flow';

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setIsOpen(true);
        }}
      />
      <Flow
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onClose={() => {
          setIsOpen(false);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

`Flow.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
export function Flow({ isOpen, onClose }) {
  if (!isOpen) return null;
  return <div onClick={onClose}>close</div>;
}
```

`MyComponent.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
import { Flow } from './Flow';

describe('67027129', () => {
  it('should set open to true', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Flow).prop('isOpen')).toBeFalsy();
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find(Flow).prop('isOpen')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should set open to false', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find(Flow).prop('isOpen')).toBeTruthy();
    wrapper.find(Flow).invoke('onClose')();
    expect(wrapper.find(Flow).prop('isOpen')).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67027129/MyComponent.test.tsx (10.173 s)
  67027129
    ✓ should set open to true (37 ms)
    ✓ should set open to false (19 ms)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |   76.92 |        0 |      75 |   81.82 |                   
 Flow.tsx        |      40 |        0 |       0 |      50 | 3-4               
 MyComponent.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.908 s, estimated 13 s
```