# How to test child component rendered or not with isRequired props and onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

This is `MasterView.jsx`

```
function MasterView(props) {
    return (
        <FilterCard title="Pass" onClick={() =>setFilter([{ id: PASSED}])}/>
        <FilterCard title="fail" onClick={() =>setFilter([{ id: Failed}])}/>
   )
}
```

This is `MasterViewSpec.jsx`

```
describe('<MasterView />', () => {  
    test('renders Child component', () => {
        const history = createMemoryHistory('/dashboard')
        const wrapper = mount(<MasterView history={history} />);
        expect(wrapper.find(<FilterCard title="Passed" onClick={() => setActiveFilters([{ id: 'passed' }])} />).length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

Getting below issue -

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: 1
Received: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

From enzyme [mount documentation](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html):

> Note: unlike shallow or static rendering, full rendering actually mounts the component in the DOM, [...]

And from [shallow documentation](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html#shallow-rendering-api):

> Shallow rendering is useful to constrain yourself to testing a component as a unit, and to ensure that your tests aren't indirectly asserting on behavior of child components.

So if you are trying to find `FilterCard` you must use `shallow` instead of `mount`.

You are also using the `.find()` method in the wrong way. You must use an [enzyme selector](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#enzyme-selectors) as argument. So your test code should be like:

```
describe('<MasterView />', () => {  
    test('renders Child component', () => {
        const history = createMemoryHistory('/dashboard')
        const wrapper = shallow(<MasterView history={history} />);
        expect(wrapper.find(FilterCard).length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

If you want to test if a specific `prop` is passed to a child component you should do something like:

```
describe('<MasterView />', () => {  
    test('renders Child component', () => {
        const history = createMemoryHistory('/dashboard')
        const wrapper = shallow(<MasterView history={history} />);
        const childTitle = wrapper.find(FilterCard).at(0).props().title;
        expect(childTitle).toEqual("Passed");
    });
});
```

If you want to find by component constructor and its properties you can use a selector like `FilterCard[title="Passed"]`.

```
describe('<MasterView />', () => {  
    test('renders Child component', () => {
        const history = createMemoryHistory('/dashboard')
        const wrapper = shallow(<MasterView history={history} />);
        expect(wrapper.find(FilterCard[title="Passed"]).length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

From [documentation](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#enzyme-selectors):

> React component name and props (Button, Button[type="submit"], etc) - however, **please note that it is strongly encouraged to find by component constructor/function and not by display name.**

my highlight.

Comment: Getting issue - Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead. when i used above code

Comment: I have 5 <FilterCard/> child elements with and each one has 6 props and one onClick function. all are required proptypes. above both the code snaps are not working

Comment: expect(wrapper.find(FilterCard).length).toEqual(1); for this line we are not checking required props. how to add that

Comment: I've just answered the question. If you want to make more checks please be more specific. What type of validation you want for the required props?. When you do a `wrapper.find(FilterCard)` you get all the `FilterCard`s children. Then you can access their properties using `.prop("title")` for example and do an `expect` later.

Comment: When i execute this-     const childTitle = wrapper.find(FilterCard).at(1).props().title;
, i am getting below issue-     Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

Comment: for this-    expect(wrapper.find(FilterCard[title="Passed"]).length).toEqual(1); issue is -     ReferenceError: title is not defined.

Comment: i just need validation for required pros as, title should be string, onclick have function, count should be number etc. there are other props is there

Comment: first I need to check child rendering and after props values

Comment: @AnusayaBorlepwar I have notice that you didn't wrap both `FilterCard`s within a `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` in the example. The function return value is not a valid `React.Node`. If it is not the problem try to use `console.log(wrapper.debug())`, it will Returns an HTML-like string of the wrapper.

Comment: thanks, wladimirguerra console.log(wrapper.debug()) doesn;t give me <Filtercard>,wrapper has 3 return statements depends on state value, console.log(wrapper.debug()) gives me first return html, <Filtercard> is in 3rd return statement. how to test it?

Comment: I see. Look, to understand the big picture here you must improve your example. As I understand the `MasterView` return value depends on its internal state. To proper test it you could force it states using `wrapper.setState()` see [docs](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/setState.html#setstatenextstate-callback--self) to understand how to use it.

Comment: Here hooks are used. I am new to uitest cases, i don't know how to handle/test useState and useEffect

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60148368/3776661). It might help enlighten you on how to test with hooks.

Comment: In my example we are updating state value in useEffect and depends on state value return statement will get executed. I need to test all the three return statements or either the third return which has <FilterCard/>